# Tool to compute SHA256 Tree Hash

Tags: amazon-glacier, hash

I've started using [AWS Glacier](http://aws.amazon.com/glacier/), and noticed that it hashes the files using an algorithm called *SHA-256 Tree Hash*.

To my surprise, this algorithm is [different from SHA-256](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=103970), so I can't use the tools I'm used to, to compare hashes and verify file integrity.

Do you know a Windows tool, if possible integrated in the context menu, to compute the **SHA-256 Tree Hash** of a file?

I'd also accept a Linux command-line tool, as a second choice :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12058011/reverse-tree-building-with-an-odd-number-of-children explains what the SHA-256 Tree Hash is, but I don't know of any ready-made programs to do it.

Comment: Questions that are effectively requests for product recommendations are off-topic for ServerFault. Please see: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: @Adrian Thanks. But I've read that link, and can't see how it relates to my question. I'm not asking for the *best tool* to do the job, but instead if such a tool *exists*, and where to find it. I've found the answer to my question anyway, so no worries.

Comment: The 'if exists and where to find it' part is what makes it a 'Shopping' question. If you have any questions about how that works, I definitely encourage you to visit Meta.Serverfault and inquire there.

Comment: If a question distills to "I'm looking for $PRODUCT with $FEATURES" then it's a shopping Question. This one is "I'm looking for *a utility* with *SHA-256 Tree Hash capabilities*."

Comment: Say I got your point, how/where should I have asked this question, then?

Comment: Years later... I am proposing a place for this type of question, and referencing this question as a good question without a home... http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82757/cloud-computing-platforms?referrer=I67NTAGkhSwgCqb_Ka-8vA2

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After a bit more research, it looks like the concept of *SHA-256 Tree Hash* is something specific to Amazon Glacier, hence the difficulty to find any tool that supports it.

However, the Glacier documentation provides [sample code to compute the hash](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/checksum-calculations.html#checksum-calculations-examples), in Java and C#.
Both compile into a command-line tool that computes the hash of the file given as an argument.

I just copied and pasted the C# code in the free Visual C# 2010 Express, compiled it, and I now have the command line tool I was looking for!

Comment: Just for future reference. There's also a Ruby gem that can be installed and used to calculate the SHA2-256 treehash sum: https://github.com/erichmenge/treehash

Comment: Isn't the AWS tree hash just a [Merkle tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree) with SHA-256?

Comment: I've created a Docker image to run this sample code: https://hub.docker.com/r/ggarnier/glacier-sha256-tree-hash/

Comment: Here's a java repo that implements the example code from the AWS documentation: https://github.com/davesque/treehash.  Just clone the repo, make sure you have the Java SDK installed, and do `make` on the command line.  Then run `treehash <file1> <file2> ...`.

Comment: Here a pure bash implementation using openssl: https://github.com/tkb-/glaciertools

Comment: This question is a duplicate of:
https://serverfault.com/questions/643222/how-to-generate-amazon-glacier-sha-256-tree-hash-for-a-file-locally
Follow the above link for more detailed and up-to-date answers

Comment: @Jason The linked question is actually a duplicate of this one, coming 2 years later. It's actually funny that it has not been closed as well as a "*product recommendation*" as they like to call it.