# How to generate Amazon Glacier SHA-256 Tree Hash for a file locally?

Tags: amazon-glacier, hash

To verify my files have uploaded correctly, is there a tool to generate the Amazon Glacier Tree Hash SHA-256 for files locally?

Answer (score 6):

[boto](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/boto) has a utility function to do this.

Here's a wrapper script to turn it into a command line tool

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys
import argparse
import boto

from boto.glacier.utils import compute_hashes_from_fileobj

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='compute amazon tree hashes of files')
parser.add_argument("--quiet", "-q", action='store_true')
parser.add_argument("filename", nargs='+')
args = parser.parse_args()

for filename in args.filename:
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        sha, tree = compute_hashes_from_fileobj(f)
        if args.quiet:
           print tree
        else:
            print filename + ":", tree
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorted, I made a quick Windows tool from Amazons own source to compute the hash.

https://mega.co.nz/#!HBMQ0ZSL!l0p0AamSpoFxKwDtJU03_uTi9t9hJ-6EVURmOSXSP3Y

Comment: This is a nice simple solution that works well for Windows GUI. Would be nice if it was open-source though.

Answer (score 2):

Glacier documentation provides a [sample code to compute SHA256 tree hash](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/checksum-calculations.html#checksum-calculations-examples).

I've built a [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/ggarnier/glacier-sha256-tree-hash/) to run this sample code. You can use it to compute SHA256 tree hash for multiple files:

`` docker run -it --rm -v `pwd`:/app ggarnier/glacier-sha256-tree-hash:latest <file1> <file2> ... ``

Answer (score 0):

There is a bash script implementation using openssl here: https://github.com/numblr/glaciertools